# Mapreduce error: Failed to setup local dir

Tags: windows, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm running mapreduce wordcount example on hadoop installed on windows 8. I got the error as below. It sounds like a security permission issue. But I'm not very sure. 
I added a property to yarn-site.xml file as

```
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
        <value>c:\hadoop\tmp-nm</value>
</property>
```

Any idea would be very helpful!

```
15/07/15 11:01:54 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/07/15 11:01:55 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your
application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
15/07/15 11:01:56 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
15/07/15 11:01:56 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
15/07/15 11:01:57 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1436976054610_0001
15/07/15 11:01:57 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1436976054610_0001
15/07/15 11:01:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1436976054610_0001/
15/07/15 11:01:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1436976054610_0001
15/07/15 11:02:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1436976054610_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/07/15 11:02:03 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/07/15 11:02:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1436976054610_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1436976054610_0001 failed 2
times due to AM Container for appattempt_1436976054610_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://localhost:8088/cluster/app/application_1436976054610_0001Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Failed to setup local dir c:/hadoop/tmp-nm, which was marked as good.
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
15/07/15 11:02:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. It is a permissions issue and you basically need to change ownership to your user account of all the folders in your c:/hadoop/tmp-nm folder. Trying to change ownership only of tmp-nm will not work, as you have to manually change ownership of all the subfolders inside tmp-nm.