# Hadoop 2.6 Mapreduce permissions incorrectly set on Windows

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have installed Hadoop 2.6 on Windows as a test bed for some software that is dependent on Hadoop.  The install worked correctly as far as I can tell. I have Hadoop saved in `C:\Hadoop` and my temporary folder in `C:\hadooptemp`.  I followed this tutorial on getting it set up:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BweVwq32koypYm1QWHNvRTZWTm8/view

When I run the hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar for pi, as provided in the tutorial, I get the following output:

```
Number of Maps  = 2
Samples per Map = 5
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Starting Job
15/08/27 15:55:10 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /155.41.90.116:8032
15/08/27 15:55:12 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
15/08/27 15:55:12 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
15/08/27 15:55:13 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1440705227041_0001
15/08/27 15:55:14 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1440705227041_0001
15/08/27 15:55:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://mycomp:8088/proxy/application_1440705227041_0001/
15/08/27 15:55:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1440705227041_0001
15/08/27 15:55:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1440705227041_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/08/27 15:55:35 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/08/27 15:55:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1440705227041_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1440705227041_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1440705227041_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://mycomp:8088/proxy/application_1440705227041_0001/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
```

*Diagnostics: Failed to setup local dir /hadooptemp/nm-local-dir, which was marked as good.*

```
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
15/08/27 15:55:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
Job Finished in 25.444 seconds
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://155.41.90.116:8020/user/me/QuasiMonteCarlo_1440705304456_1878814183/out/reduce-out
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1751)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1774)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.estimatePi(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:314)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.run(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:354)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.main(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:363)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

From what I have been tracing with the exitCode: -1000, to comes down to Hadoop not being able to setup the local directory with appropriate permissions. I believe in the tutorial I am using above, that is why they disable the User Account Controls. Whether or not I do this, I get the same error.

I also found a similar issue in this link:
[Mapreduce error: Failed to setup local dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435849/mapreduce-error-failed-to-setup-local-dir/31594413#31594413)

I tried to follow as they said, and make both `C:\Hadoop` and `C:\hadooptemp` owned by my user account through the folder properties, security, and advanced settings. I was listed as the owner before, and I have full control access to the folder according to this. Either that isn't the issue, or I have incorrectly assigned the ownership to my account.

Finally, in my YARN Node Manager, I get the following error that seems to possibly be related which pops up in a few places:

```
15/08/27 15:55:34 WARN localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Permissions incorrectly set for dir /hadooptemp/nm-local-dir/usercache, should be rwxr-xr-x, actual value = rwxrwxr-x
```

It seems that I have too many permissions, as it states they are incorrectly set?  I can't imagine this is the cause of the issue, that my group also has write permissions, but I couldn't figure out how to alter that in Windows.

Any help on figuring out the details of the permissions problem to fix this error would be appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, were you using a work computer (with a work domain) outside of the office? I recently ran into this issue, went as far as granting `Everyone` full control permissions on the relevant folders in Windows, and still got the error. Finally VPN'd into my domain, and BOOM, no issue.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom Thank you, I would've never thought to try that and it immediately resolved my problem. Any ideas what causes this or how one might fix things so that signing in to VPN isn't required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case was due to Windows Domain not reachable. Connect your pc to windows Domain.
Here my yarn config

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
     <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>0.0.0.0</value>
    </property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
        <value>c:\my\hadoop-2.7.1\tmp-nm</value>
</property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage</name>
        <value>98.5</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

also see https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/SecureContainer.html

Answer (score 3):

I bypassed the `Permissions incorrectly set` message after running `start-yarn.sh` as administrator in a Windows command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

Run command prompt as administrator and the use commands `start-dfs` and `start-yarn`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little old, but I ran into a similar permissions issue today and was able to solve it with the following:

1. Make sure your properties are set correctly in yarn-site.xml as @venergiac mentions above. Added here for completeness:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>0.0.0.0</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
        <value>file:///d:/hadoop/hadoop-3.1.0/tmp</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

2. If, like me, this does not fix the error, simply fix exactly what it's telling you is the problem (i.e. the folder permissions). This is a little tricky since there is no `chmod` out of the box on windows, but this is why we have cygwin! Open cygwin terminal and use basic `chmod` commands to edit file permissions to exactly match the value hdfs is expecting. For example, based on OP's log output:

> Permissions incorrectly set for dir /hadooptemp/nm-local-dir/usercache, should be rwxr-xr-x, actual value = rwxrwxr-x

we can simply run:

`chmod g-w /hadooptemp/nm-local-dir/usercache`

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar error. The reason was that

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
    <value>D:\hadoop\tmp</value>
</property
```

refer to 'D' drive which is exFAT. When I changed location to NTFS, it started working.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me...Run as administrator start-all.cmd

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue was creating due to my pc was secure by company. I connected to my company vpn resolved my issue.

Comment: This answer isn't related to the actual problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32215148)